# Adding margin totals to table created with R package "tables"

Tags: r, margin, tabular

The following code snippet creates a simple 2x2 contingency table using the "tables" package in R.

```
require(tables)
TAB <- latex(tabular((Gears=factor(gear)) ~  (Carburetors=carb)*(Format(digits=2)*
Percent("col")+ 1), data=mtcars))
```

What would be the easiest way of adding row and column totals to this table?

Comment: I guess you have to define 'easiest'. :)

Comment: Are `rowSums` and `colSums` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Roman and @Simon, thanks for your answers. I should have been more specific here, I guess... My question is how to add those margins using the `tabular()` command of the "Tables" package. The output yielded by `tabular()` is a list, so `rowSums`, `colSums` or `addmargins()` don't work here. I suppose you would have to change the formula passed to `tabular()` somehow, but I haven't been able to figure it out how to do that, despite the extensive package documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are showing how to do it for row totals (which is what the `+1` is doing) and using the same method for the columns is effective:

```
tabular((Gears=factor(gear)) +1~  (Carburetors=carb)*(Format(digits=2)*
        Percent("col")+ 1), data=mtcars)

       Carburetors    
 Gears Percent     All
 3      47         15 
 4      38         12 
 5      16          5 
 All   100         32
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! I admit I should have tried harder to understand the formula in the first place...